# Utilização de módulo do Python em Django

Tags: python, django

Estou começando com Django e Python agora e tenho uma dúvida que talvez pareça idiota: Posso utilizar os módulos e funções do python - e outros instalados - normalmente em uma aplicação Django?

Comment: Não só pode como deve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o Django é um framework python, os modulos desenvolvidos para Python são perfeitamente utilizáveis dentro do Django.

Um exemplo ilustrativo seria:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render #Importação de módulo Django
import math #Importação de um módulo Python

def calcula(request):
    numero = 4
    elevado = math.pow(numero,2) #Uso do módulo
    raiz = math.sqrt(numero) # Uso do Módulo 
    context = {'elevado': elevado, 'raiz':raiz}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Cálculos usando o módulo MATH</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Exemplo simples do uso de Módulos do Python</h1>
    <p>O numero 4 elevado a 2 é {{elevado}}</p>
    <p>A raiz de 4 é  {{raiz}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você é livre para usar os módulos do Python , mas tome cuidado para nao procurar alguma funcionalidade do python que ja seja implementada no django de forma mais eficiente. Para isso de uma olhada nos [módulos Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/py-modindex/).

Answer (score 0):

Sim, claro!
Inclusive todos as libs disponiveis no https://pypi.python.org/pypi podem ser instaladas e utilizadas no projeto.